# Get form array data from Busboy

Tags: arrays, node.js, forms, busboy

How do I get array form data using [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy)?

In route:

```
req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val){
  //fieldname is string, expecting array
  //'bunnies[gray]', etc...
});
```

And my view:

```
form(method="post" action="/post/path" enctype="multipart/form-data")
    input(name="bunnies[gray]")
    input(name="bunnies[white]")
    input(name="bunnies[black]")
    input(name="bunnies[brown]")
    input(name="bunnies[purple]")
```

Answer (score 1):

So `busboy` isn't stupid -- `multipart/form-data` does not by default support arrays in the same way as a `JSON` body does.

Requests with `arrayName[n]` as field names will not be parsed as arrays by `busboy` alone -- such a payload will have still have to be parsed manually.

One *can* manually parse these array values using one of these other answers...

... but if manually parsing arrays is undesired, one may consider using **[co-busboy](https://github.com/cojs/busboy)** instead using this option:

```js
autoFields: true
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is rather old, but in case someone else stumbles upon this problem, here's what I did:

```
var arr = new Array();

req.pipe(req.busboy);

req.busboy.on('field', function(key, value) {
  if(key === 'array_name[]') {
    arr.push(value);
  }
});

req.busboy.on('finish', function() {
  console.log(arr);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Question if 5 years old but it gave me a hint. I am coming from PHP background and didn't realize that Busboy is this stupid, so if you want to process array of fields, you need to actually process them like this:

```
busboy.on('field', (fieldname, val) => {
    if (fieldname.indexOf('[]') !== -1) {
        let fn = fieldname.replace('[]', '');
        if (typeof req.body[fn] === 'undefined') {
            req.body[fn] = [];
        }
        req.body[fn].push(val);
    } else {
        req.body[fieldname] = val;
    }
});
```

Hope to save someone else a few hours of debugging ...